# ¿ Como compartir imagen en las redes sociales, android?

Tags: java, android, imagen, retrofit, android-glide

Estoy tratando de compartir una imagen en las redes sociales, la cual obtengo desde una  url he intentado diversas formas y no lo he logrado, utilizo retrofit2 para mostrar el contenido de la aplicación.

Muchas gracias de antemano

**Aquí obtengo la url de la imagen**

```
           Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(appointment.getmImage())
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .override(250, 120)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(mContext, 10, 0)
            )
            .into(holder.imagee);
```

**Este es el código que utilizo para compartir en las redes sociales**

```
btnshared.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, titulocompartir.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, comentariocompartir.getText().toString());
                        imagee.buildDrawingCache();
                        Bitmap image= imagee.getDrawingCache();
                        extras.putParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);


                }

            });
```

las redes sociales estarán disponibles dependiendo de las aplicaciones que tenga instaladas, si compartir normal lo hace solo texto pero el problema viene cuando intento compartir una imagen no la carga en el post

Comment: alguien me ayuda por favor?

Comment: las redes sociales estaran disponibles dependiendo de las aplicaciones que tenga instaladas, si compartir normal lo hace solo texto pero el problema viene cuando intento compartir una imagen no la carga en el post

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede realizar mediante [Intent.createChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Si puedes obtener el `Bitmap` de la imagen deseada, tienes que guardarla a disco y de esa forma podría enviarse mediante [Intent.createChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), para guardarla y posteriormente obtener acceso a la imagen, es necesario definir un [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), puedes revisar en stackoverflow donde se encuentra información relacionada a esto.

Como ejemplo te dejo este tutorial:

Primeramente define un provider en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, esto dentro del tag `<application>` :

```
 <application
        ...
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.providers.FileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>
```

posteriormente agrega el archivo donde seran definidos los paths del archivo dentro de `/res/xml`, por default no existe /xml , así que debes crearlo. Dentro agrega el archivo `paths.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="shared_images" path="imagenes/"/>
</paths>
```

de esta forma se tendrán permisos para acceder al archivo en disco, este es un ejemplo usando un Asynctask, aquí puedes reemplazar la obtención del Bitmap desde un url por la obtención del Bitmap desde el ImageView:

```
imagee.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image= imagee.getDrawingCache();
```

que sería llamado de esta forma `new sendImageTask().execute();` :

```
   public class sendImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        try {
                           URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png");
                            Bitmap imagen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                            // Salva bitmap a disco.
                            try {

                                File cachePath = new File(getCacheDir(), "imagenes"); //path cache.
                                cachePath.mkdirs(); // Crea directorio si no existe.
                                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/imagen.jpg"); // Escribe imagen.
                                imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                stream.close();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            File imagePath = new File(getCacheDir(), "imagenes"); //obtiene directorio.
                            File newFile = new File(imagePath, "imagen.jpg"); //obtiene imagen.

                            String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".providers.FileProvider";

                            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), PACKAGE_NAME, newFile);

                            if (contentUri != null) {

                                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
                                shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
                                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Elige una aplicación:"));

                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

            return null;
        }


    }
```

con esto podrás compartir la imagen en cualquier red social o aplicación instalada que soporte el envío de imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]